# php curl DOMdocument traverse multi Arrays

Tags: php, arrays, curl, xpath, domdocument

i have a small issue with the following function DOM
I want to save the data in one array , but what I have as a result is the separate data in a separate arrays. How can I combine the all the data in one array?

In the $html variable is the html content from site.html taken via curl.

site.html

```
 <div class="wraper">
   <div class="box"> Title </div>
   <div class="value"> 1 </div>
   <div class="value"> 2 </div>
   <div class="value"> 3 </div>
   <div class="box"> Title2 </div>
   <div class="value"> 4 </div>
   <div class="value"> 5 </div>
   <div class="value"> 6 </div>
</div>
```

this is my code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();    
@$dom->loadHTML($html);

$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$expression = '//*[(self::div or self::span) and contains(concat(" ", normalize-           space(@class), " "), "wraper")]';

foreach ($xpath->evaluate($expression) as $node) {
  if ($node->hasChildNodes()) {
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $node2) {
      echo $node2->nodeValue;
    }
  }
}
```

I got every nodeValue as new array[0] and there as first element, because of the foreach loop.

I want to get the values on like this.

```
array (

     "0"  =>    array([0] => "Title "
                      [1] => 1
                      [2] => 2
                      [3] => 3), 

     "1"   =>   array([0] => "Title2 "
                      [1] => 4
                      [2] => 5
                      [3] => 6) 
   )
```

thank you

Comment: This code doesn't produce arrays, it just outputs as `echo $node2->nodeValue;`. Please post the code where you are building or appending to your array so we can help to correct problems there.

Comment: there is the code   `$v = $node2->nodeValue;
                     global $arr;
                     array_push($arr, $v);  `  but how I can differ betweeen the 2 "box" divs as sparate elements. I want save the 4 values in one row in the Database for exp. in MySql